# Mysql replace and change

Tags: mysql, sql, database, data-analysis, dbeaver

I´m having problems with this
[column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ9mF.png) here are some values:

```
19790.22

10357.94

(124.39)

7608.13

34957.47

(4004.40)

21608.10

33707.22
```

I need to do an update with a case..

when the num has (), then replace with '' (nothing) and multiply by -1 (since is a negative numer). I know  how to do the replace, but can't manage to multiply  by -1 when the have () and not every reg.

THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Comment: What is a column data type?

Comment: @AndreyBelykh is varchar..

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones no.. can't with that

Comment: Why doesn't that work? Please edit your question to expand on the issue, because I believe that's the basic logic you're looking for. Otherwise a regular update with a condition should do it: `UPDATE table SET id = CONCAT('-', REPLACE(REPLACE(id, '(', ''), ')', '')) WHERE id LIKE "(%)";`

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones YES!!! that i think might help!

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones THANKS